# Sublime Text Editor 3 doesn't show traceback when running Python code

Tags: python, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text, python3

Yesterday I installed ST3 and installed some plugins, but I noticed that if Python has a syntax error then it shows an error. But when a statement has a non-syntax error, then it shows nothing. Like this code doesn't throw any traceback.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

But when I run the same code from the terminal then I do get a traceback:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I show the traceback in my Sublime Text Editor? I am pretty sure that the problem is not occurring because of a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text cannot handle input through it's build system. Therefore, your  `input` just blocks and the code below it never executes, so you never hit the error that would cause a traceback. The easiest workaround is to execute your code via a plugin like [SublimeREPL](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) instead of the build-system.

Comment: It didn't wrok...!